# Do I need to use both isset() and $post_variable="value"? Why not just the latter?

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

In W3Schools' PHP tutorial, they do this to make sure the gender-button on a form is still selected after the user submits a faulty form:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>
value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender"
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>
value="male">Male
```

Notice the use of both `isset()` and `$gender="the_gender"`. I have managed to get the same functionality by only checking the gender:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if ($gender=="male") echo "checked";?>>Male
```

So my question is, why does W3Schools bother with using the `isset()` function?

Comment: Don't use that tutorial! It appears to depend on [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). Having found [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp), I see it teaches code that is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Avoid it! It is a security nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Any other tutorial you recommend instead?

Comment: Because you first need to know if `$gender` EXISTS, and then you need to know what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function check variable exists or not. If you don't have `$gender` and use it, cause warning that say `$gender` is not defined.